# difference between dynamic data binding and scaffold

Tags: terminology, dynamic-data, scaffold

What is the exact difference on "SCAFFOLD" and "Dynamic Data Binding" , are they same ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Scaffolding means to me : build the interface for the field. Per MSDN : "Scaffolding is the mechanism of generating web page templates based on database schemas."

Binding generally means to link the persisted (usually DB) data values for each interface element.